# Footnotes too close to the text in KOMA scrartcl class

Tags: margins, footnotes, koma-script

I use the `scrartcl` KOMA class and I find the footnote too close to the bottom of my text. How can I change it? I would like to

1. have more space between them and
2. have more text on a single page.

I use

```
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14,BCOR=2mm, oneside,BCOR=12mm, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
```

with `hyperref` and `biblatex`.

Additionally, and strangely enough, changing the values of `DIV` in the above line has no effect on my paper... while changing the font size does (from `12pt` to `11pt for instance). Any ideas?

Here is a MWE fully loaded with my packages and a text from the creative commons legal code

```
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=12,BCOR=2mm, oneside,BCOR=12mm, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[Large]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,citestyle=authoryear,isbn=false,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont} 
    {}
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, linkcolor=blue,  citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,pdftitle={Your title here},allbordercolors=blue,
    pdfauthor={ },
    pdfsubject={News},
    pdfkeywords={ },
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true ,pdfstartview=Fit      }

\usepackage{hypcap}

\begin{document}
You may distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform the Work only under the terms of this License, and You must include a copy of, or the Uniform Resource Identifier for, this License with every copy or phonorecord of the Work You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform. You may not offer or impose any terms on the Work that restrict the terms of this License or the ability of a recipient of the Work to exercise the rights granted to that recipient under the terms of the License. You may not sublicense the Work. You must keep intact all notices that refer to this License and to the disclaimer of warranties. When You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform the Work, You may not impose any technological measures on the Work that restrict the ability of a recipient of the Work from You to exercise the rights granted to that recipient under the terms of the License. This Section 4(a) applies to the Work as incorporated in a Collective Work, but this does not require the Collective Work apart from the Work itself to be made subject to the terms of this License. If You create a Collective Work, upon notice from any Licensor You must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Collective Work any credit as required by Section 4(d), as requested. If You create a Derivative Work, upon notice from any Licensor You must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Derivative Work any credit as required by Section 4(d), as requested.\footnote{whoa look at all this white space wasted below!! and look how close this footnote is from the above text!!!!}
You may distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform a Derivative Work only under: (i) the terms of this License; (ii) a later version of this License with the same License Elements as this License; or, (iii) either the unported Creative Commons license or a Creative Commons license for another jurisdiction (either this or a later license version) that contains the same License Elements as this License (e.g. Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 (Unported)) ("the Applicable License"). You must include a copy of, or the Uniform Resource Identifier for, the Applicable License with every copy or phonorecord of each Derivative Work You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform. You may not offer or impose any terms on the Derivative Works that restrict the terms of the Applicable License or the ability of a recipient of the Work to exercise the rights granted to that recipient under the terms of the Applicable License. You must keep intact all notices that refer to the Applicable License and to the disclaimer of warranties. When You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform the Derivative Work, You may not impose any technological measures on the Derivative Work that restrict the ability of a recipient of the Derivative Work from You to exercise the rights granted to that recipient under the terms of the Applicable License. This Section 4(b) applies to the Derivative Work as incorporated in a Collective Work, but this does not require the Collective Work apart from the Derivative Work itself to be made subject to the terms of the Applicable License.
\footnote{whoa look at all this white space wasted below!!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Noobie Either DIV from Komascript or geometry.

Comment: ah ok I see.. there is a conflict between geometry and KOMA...

Comment: however....i still do not know how can I increase the distance between the text and the footnote ;-) do you have an idea? many many thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the space between text and footnote with `\skip\footins`.  See the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[Latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} % generates dummy document

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Distance text -- footnote
\setlength{\skip\footins}{10mm plus 2mm}


\begin{document}
\Blindtext
Footnote as requested\footnote{This is a footnote! This is a footnote! 
  This is a footnote! This is a footnote! This is a footnote! }
\Blindtext
Footnote as requested\footnote{This is a footnote! This is a footnote! 
  This is a footnote! This is a footnote! This is a footnote! }

\end{document}
```

You can control the type setting area with the KOMA-Script option `DIV=xx`. Try for xx 12 til 18. Larger number means smaller margins.  That the bottom margin is bigger than the top or left margin is wanted. That is a very pretty typography.

Result with MWE:
[image]

Comment: What is that 'plus' doing there? The spacing is 10mm+2mm = 12mm ?